# How can I tell if iAds are being requested?

Tags: ios, iad

I've got iAds working in my app, but there are still some frustrating moments. While testing, how can you tell if the iAds requests are being made? I've implemented both 
`didFailToReceiveAdWithError` and `bannerViewDidLoadAd`, but when testing in both the simulator and on a test device, my screen that should be displaying iAds shows no banner ad at all for long periods of time. There is also no triggering of NSLogs in either `didFailToReceiveAdWithError` or `bannerViewDidLoadAd`. It can take as long as five minutes waiting on that screen before an IAd request fails or loads an iAd, so, yes, iAds eventually does work. But I would like to know earlier in the whole process.

I've gone to the Settings-->Developer section in both the simulator and on the test device and set Fill Rate to 100% and Time to 15 seconds . But it seems to have no effect on the appearance of iAds.

I'd like to see some indicator that a request for an iAd is going out from my app. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a web proxy (like Charles Proxy http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to watch the network communication between the simulator and the various hosts. You may have to get it configured to use SSL which is tricky.

You can also get it to work with an actual device you can also use your dev machine as a proxy, that's a real bear to get working depending upon your networking situation.

Note: I've not actually done this for iAds, but for other traffic I do it all the time. I've no relation to Charles Proxy except as a very satisfied customer.

Comment: Thanks! The software is more than I expected and should solve a few other frustrations too.

Comment: I figured I'd use the free trial until it proved itself. I paid for it about 15 minutes after I first used it.

Answer (score 0):

Set iadBanner delegate to self

Comment: I do set the iAdBanner delegate to self in my viewWillAppear with `_adOnStarter.delegate = self;` where `_adOnStarter` is the synthesized instance of my IB AdBannerView IBOutlet.